# (Java) How to write to RTF file with colored text

Tags: java, file, text, colors, rtf

I already know how to write to an rtf file in Java, but is there a way to do it with colored texts? I want to do it in a way that would let me alternate the color between words.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this [link](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading16) to the documentation about color in RTF. You need to declare a color table and then select the color of your choosing for foreground/background.

Hope this helps